# How to make Divide(column1/column2) in hibernate criteria projections

Tags: hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I need to perform `select item.itemName, (item.Qty * item.Price)` as total Price from Item item' in Hibernate criteria query. i tried,

```
objCriteria = objSession.createCriteria(ItemVO.class, "IT")
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("IT.name"), "itemName")
.add(Projections.sqlProjection("(QTY * cost)", new Float[] {"TotalCost"}, ( new Type[] {Hibernate.Float}))))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ConsumableDTO.class));
```

But I need with HQL name instead of direct sql query column name. how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are still interested in this, but I believe you can get this working by actually putting the 'sum' keyword in your sqlProjection.

Your query would then look like:

```
objCriteria = objSession.createCriteria(ItemVO.class, "IT")
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("IT.name"), "itemName")
.add(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(QTY * cost)", new Float[] {"TotalCost"}, ( new Type[] {Hibernate.Float}))))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ConsumableDTO.class));
```

This should result in returning an Object[] for each item that matches, with the name in the first array element, and the computed 'totalCost' in the second.

Comment: This sort of advanced examples is hard to come by.